# Infer a mapped parameter type in typescript

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I'm working with a library that has an interesting type declaration (simplified):

```js
class Emitter {
    public on<EventName extends 'streamCreated' | 'streamDestroyed'> (eventName: EventName, callback: (event: {
        streamCreated: {id: number};
        streamDestroyed: {reason: string};
    }[EventName]) => void): void;
}
```

And I'm trying to type the event in the callback that I provide:

```js
const callback = (event: StreamDestroyedEvent) => console.log(event.reason);
emitter.on('streamDestroyed', callback);
```

However "StreamDestroyedEvent" doesn't exist. It's not provided by the library, but rather exists only in that anonymous eventmapping, so I instead try to infer it:

```js
type InferCallback<T, E> = T extends (eventName: E, event: infer R) => void ? R : never;
type InferCallbackEvent<T, E> = InferCallback<T, E> extends (event: infer P) => void ? P : never;
type StreamDestroyedEvent = InferCallbackEvent<Emitter['on'], 'streamDestroyed'>;
```

However, instead of giving me a type of `{reason: string}` it get the union type `{reason: string;} | {id: number;}`. How can I get the right type, or is this as close as I'm going to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd like to basically "plug in" a type for the `EventName` type parameter.  While TypeScript supports this when *calling* a generic function, it doesn't do a good job *representing* such types in the type system itself.  To do so would fully would require support for [higher rank types](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/115/higher-rank-and-higher-kinded-types), which aren't really part of the language.  And the `emitter.on` function by itself doesn't really let you call it "partially" so that you plug in `EventName` with the first parameter and then have the compiler tell *you* what the type of the second parameter should be.

Before TypeScript 3.4 came out I'd probably say getting this information out of the compiler would be impossible.  I'd try something like

```
emitter.on("streamDestroyed", x => {
  type StreamDestroyedEvent = typeof x; // can't get it out of the scope though!
})
```

and then be unable to get the `StreamDestroyedEvent` type to escape the function.

TypeScript 3.4 introduced improved support [higher order type inference from generic functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions).  You still can't represent what you're doing purely in the type system, but now we can define a function that gives us something we can that does the "partial" calling and retains the type information we need.

Here is a [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) function which takes a multi-argument function and returns a new function of one argument that returns another function of the remaining arguments:

```
const curry = <T, U extends any[], R>(
  cb: (t: T, ...args: U) => R
) => (t: T) => (...args: U) => cb(t, ...args);
```

If you call `curry` on `emitter.on`, and then call *that* with `"streamDestroyed"`, (in TS3.4+) you get a function which takes a callback which takes a `StreamDestroyedEvent`, which you can now capture:

```
const streamDestroyedFunc = curry(emitter.on.bind(emitter))("streamDestroyed")
type StreamDestroyedEvent = Parameters<Parameters<typeof streamDestroyedFunc>[0]>[0];
// type StreamDestroyedEvent = { reason: string; }
```

Note that the actual runtime behavior of the above isn't the point; I tried to make sure it would actually do something reasonable, but you could also have just used type assertions to lie to the compiler about what was happening, as long as you don't get a runtime error when you run it:

```
const fakeCurry: typeof curry = () => () => null!;
const fakeOn: Emitter["on"] = null!;
const fakeFunc = fakeCurry(fakeOn)("streamDestroyed");
type SDE2 = Parameters<Parameters<typeof fakeFunc>[0]>[0]; // same thing
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-XgA8uwuyZjAXSvBwrwDEiX4QD+Z7-leIDjsm8AATed7phhwElu89ajpWYY1su8DgoY6AAExIr2-YwN2tGiF2nCPuhyGoXOs7TgMtz8hGfgBEEoSvg4fRuJCq4Nt8zbun+rAQCAjwQKwLQRH0jy7uwxFAA)